# How to link .dll into visual studio 2008?

Tags: vb.net, dll

I'm doing VB coding using Visual Studio 2008.
How to import a .dll file into my program?
Can anyone help me please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add the reference (From your menu **Project->Add Reference** and browse for the dll file)

   2. Put **Imports DLL.Namespace** at the top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the DLL...

- Right click references in the project explorer
- Click on the browse tab
- Browse to your dll
- Add a using statement in your code which points to said DLL

Comment: I think you mean Imports rather than using :o)